# blur is cancelling click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The blur event seems to be cancelling the click event.

When a user clicks on an image, a panel should slide into view.

When the panel is visible, clicking anywhere outside of the panel should slide the panel back up and out of the view.

The problem is when I have more than of these modules and I click the second image while the first panel is open the blur function fires but no the click event.

```
    toggleContent : function () {

        var wrapper = $('.wrapper'),
            targetClass = '.moreInfo',
            eContent = wrapper.find('.more');

        wrapper.on('click', targetClass, function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

                return false;
            }
            else {

                eContent = $(this).focus().parent().next();
                eContent.slideDown('normal');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }

        }).on('blur', targetClass, function (e) {

            eContent = $(this).parent().next();

            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){
                eContent.slideUp('normal');
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing these are just regular elements, and not form inputs etc. so using focus and blur doesn't make much sense, and even if there are hacks to set focus to just about anything with tabindex etc. it doesn't seem like a good event to use for this ?

Comment: Can you provide an example code or jsfiddle?